# cURL error 7: Failed to connect to oauth2.googleapis.com port 443

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to use the google calendar API (from a php script in cli mode) from an OVH shared server
( see: [PHP quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php) )

After getting the code in the oAuthCallBack.php file, google gives me the following error:

> cURL error 7: Failed to connect to oauth2.googleapis.com port 443: Connection refused
> (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
> for https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token

OVH informs me that the concern does not come from them
and the server ip may be blacklisted

How can I resolve this problem ?

EDIT :
Minimal Example : (same problem with quick Start php code )

```php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
  throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient() {
  try {
    $client = new Google_Client();
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Erreur getClient :" . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
  }
  $client->setApplicationName('Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
  $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
  $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
  $client->setAccessType('offline');
  $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

  $tokenPath = 'token.json';
  if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
    $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
  }

  // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
    if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
      $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    } else {
      // Request authorization from the user.
      $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
      printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
      print 'Enter verification code: ';
      $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

      // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
      $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
      $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

      // Check to see if there was an error.
      if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
        throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
      }
    }
    // Save the token to a file.
    if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
      mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
  }
  return $client;
}


try{
// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

// Print the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
$calendarId = 'primary';
$optParams = array(
    'maxResults' => 3,
    'orderBy' => 'startTime',
    'singleEvents' => true,
    'timeMin' => '2021-03-18T10:22:53+01:00', // date('c')
);
$results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
$events = $results->getItems();

if (empty($events)) {
  print "No upcoming events found.\n";
} else {
  foreach ($events as $event) {
    $start = $event->start->dateTime;
    if (empty($start)) {
      $start = $event->start->date;
    }

    $end = $event->end->dateTime;
    if (empty($end)) {
      $end = $event->end->date;
    }

    $id = trim($event->getId());
    $etag = $event->etag;
    $htmlLink = $event->htmlLink;
    $summary = $event->summary;
    $iCalUID = $event->iCalUID;
    $description = str_replace("\r\n", "<br>", nl2br(htmlspecialchars($event->description)));


    if ($description == "description test") {
      //print_r($event);
      echo " => ID: $id  - iCalUID: $iCalUID | " . $etag . " | " . $summary . " | " . $htmlLink . " | " . $start . " - " . $end . " | " . $description . PHP_EOL;
    }
  }
}catch(Exception $e){
  echo PHP_EOL  . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL ;
}
```

Step 4: Run the sample
Run the sample using the following command:

php quickstart.php
The first time you run the sample, it will prompt you to authorize access:

Browse to the provided URL in your web browser.

If you are not already signed in to your Google account, you are be prompted to sign in. If you are signed in to multiple Google accounts, you are asked to select one account to use for the authorization.

Click the Accept button.
Copy the code you're given, paste it into the command-line prompt, and press Enter.

> > > The error appears here!

To see it, I just added a try / catch block in the code

The problem is not related to the php code, but to the creation of the token.json which it cannot recover from the google servers.
It seems that it is related to an access denied to the ip of the ovh server on which the site is running.
NB: this code works perfectly from a dedicated server.

Thanks,
Jordane

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: Hello, the question has been edited for 2 weeks. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Hello, Nobody has a solution to suggest?

Comment: fix your firewall?

Comment: Hi DalmTo, this is not a firewall issue. The same code works on dedicated servers. OVH tells us that the problem comes from a blocking by google of the IP address of the server (shared server) on which we are trying to make this code work.

Comment: How did you solve this problem?

Comment: The problem is not solved ....

Comment: checking the site using a Chrome browser incognito window worked for me

Comment: @Kym NT
  the error is not related to the internet browser... since the problem occurs in the ssh terminal of the server...